# Ansible: printing out JSON first level keys names

Tags: python, json, ansible

Example :

```
{
        "fw1": {
                "ipv4": {
                        "rtr": {

                                "ip": "1.2.3.4",
                                "net": "1.2.3.4",

                        }
                }
        },
        "fw2": {
                "ipv4": {
                        "rtr": {
                                "ip": "4.3.2.1",
                                "net": "4.3.2.1",

                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I need to list the first level keys of a json file.
 Using 'from_json).keys()' i get  a strange syntax -->
 **[u'fw1', u'fw2'].**

where do the **'u'** characters come from and how to get rid of them ? Is there any way to list the keys instead of getting them in an Array ?

Comment: `u` means that the text is unicode.

Comment: `u'unicode_string'` is a python2 thing, don't worry about getting rid of them. And array is a list of keys, so how do you want to list them?

Comment: if anyone wants to return one of the first level keys.                                      my_json: "{{ (lookup('file', 'test.json') | from_json).keys() }}"
      tasks:
        - debug: var=my_json[0] // for fist first element or my_json[1] for second and so on

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `from_json` here:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
    my_json: "{{ lookup('file','test.json') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Keys list: {{ my_json.keys() }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vars:
...
tasks:
...
  - set_fact:
      keys: "{{my_json.keys()|list}}"
  - name: Show keys as a list
    debug: var={{ item }}
    loop: "{{ keys }}"
```